# Android ListView height exceeds screen height

Tags: android

So i'm using a listview (actually [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh))

When I specify that I want the view to fill parent it actually exceeds the screen. I notice this by seeing the scrollbar disappear but I can still scroll for a bit.

Here's my view in xml:

```
<eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/transactionList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    gridlayout:layout_columnSpan="2"
    gridlayout:layout_row="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" />
```

As a hack I can fix this on my Galaxy Nexus with the following code, this fix is device specific as when viewed on a Galxay SII there's a gap at the bottom of the screen. I have a feel it is something to do with pixel densities.

Note that the 290 value below was originally 120 as this is the combined height of views at the top of the screen. I then changed it to 290 for a perfect fit. Not sure where the extra 170 is from.

```
timelineList = (PullToRefreshListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timelineList);        

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context. WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 290;
    int width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    GridLayout.LayoutParams glp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(); //LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,height/2);
    glp. height = height;
    glp. width = width;

    timelineList .setLayoutParams(glp);
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or how I can fix it for all devices?

**Update: Full Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gridlayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.product.package"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_default_2x"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        layout="@layout/header_bar" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.gridlayout.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dip"
            gridlayout:columnCount="2"
            gridlayout:rowCount="2" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                gridlayout:layout_columnSpan="2"
                gridlayout:layout_row="0"
                gridlayout:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_bg_2x"
                android:contentDescription="@string/bg_image" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
                gridlayout:layout_row="0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Product"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_photo_placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProductLogo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
                gridlayout:layout_row="0"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Product"
                android:src="@drawable/Productlogo" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/timelineList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                gridlayout:layout_columnSpan="2"
                gridlayout:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timelineEmptyMessage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                gridlayout:layout_columnSpan="2"
                gridlayout:layout_row="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/timeline_blank_message"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_text"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </com.gridlayout.GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by moving my list view outside of the GridLayout like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gridlayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.product.package"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_default_2x"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        layout="@layout/header_bar" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.gridlayout.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dip"
            gridlayout:columnCount="2"
            gridlayout:rowCount="2" >

            <!-- ## OTHER VIEWS HERE -->


        </com.gridlayout.GridLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/timelineList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            gridlayout:layout_columnSpan="2"
            gridlayout:layout_row="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use other PullToRefresh implementation [for example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) if you will have same bug then we need to try fix othervise make issue-report to developer of PullToRefreshListView and just use other librarry

Comment: You made alot of layouts it s beter to replays it by 1 Relative layout.

And try to remove android:layout_gravity="top" from listview

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. I put the listview outside the GridLayout